# Paypal REST api - callback for shipping address

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement PayPal Express checkout for a client using the PayPal REST APIs (python-rest-api-sdk). One of the issues I have right now is presenting the correct shipping rate to the customer on the PayPal page based on the customer's shipping address.

The callback was easy to implement using the Classic APIs, but I'm not sure how to do this with the new REST api.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a feature that uses the Instant Update API feature for the Classic APIs. Unfortunately, an equivalent does not currently exist for the REST APIs. You could reach out to PayPal MTS to request information about when this might be supported.